# Unable to add window ... -- permission denied for window type 2038

Tags: java, android, android-windowmanager, native-android

I'm trying to add a window in my android app but I'm facing with this issue.

I just started android development so I'm not sure what should I need to do.
I did research but couldn't find the solution yet.
This is Window.java file.

```
package serhatkaya.hp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Window {

  private Context context;
  private WindowManager windowManager;
  private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
  private View rootView;
  private WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams;

  public Window(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    this.layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.window, null);

    this.windowParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) ? WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
            : WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    initWindowParams();
    initWindow();
  }

  private DisplayMetrics getCurrentDisplayMetrics() {
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    return dm;
  }

  private void calculateSizeAndPosition(WindowManager.LayoutParams params, int widthInDp, int heightInDp) {
    DisplayMetrics dm = getCurrentDisplayMetrics();
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.width = (int) (widthInDp * dm.density);
    params.height = (int) (heightInDp * dm.density);
    params.x = (dm.widthPixels - params.width) / 2;
    params.y = (dm.heightPixels - params.height) / 2;
    
  }

  private void initWindowParams() {
    calculateSizeAndPosition(windowParams, 300, 80);
  }

  private void initWindow() {
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.window_close).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        close();
      }
    });

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.content_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Adding notes to be implemented.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
  }

  public void open() {
    try {
      windowManager.addView(rootView, windowParams);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      String d = e.getMessage();
      // Ignore exception for now, but in production, you should have some
      // warning for the user here.
    }
  }

  public void close() {
    try {
      windowManager.removeView(rootView);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // Ignore exception for now, but in production, you should have some
      // warning for the user here.
    }
  }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
      android:exported="true" android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
      android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false"
      android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

When I try to open Window with open() function.

I'm facing the issue mentioned in the title.

I tried to add permission via androidmanifest.xml and also requesting from mainactivity like this:

```
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
        android.Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG,
        android.Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS,
      android.Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,
      android.Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
    };

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    Window window = new Window(this);
    window.open();
  }
```

I faced the same issue.

Comment: What do you mean by a "Window", windows like on a PC are not really a thing in android. If by windows you mean a screen in an android app then you are doing it completely wrong

Comment: I'm trying to open a Floating Window outside the app.

Comment: first you should start by learning how to correctly request for permissions because you currently are not doing that correctly and also not asking for the system window permission correctly

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
  // ask for permission
 Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
      Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
  startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

 
}
```

I found requesting permission for opening alert windows are changed after android 6.0

I requested permission like this and problem solved.

Note: startActivityForResult(intent,1) usage is deprecated so you may want to change it.